# Convert 12VDC fan controller output to TTL signal of laser?

Tags: level-shifting, ttl

I'm adding a laser cutter to my 3D printer.  I want to repurpose the cooling fan output to control the laser.  My laser has a power supply which accepts a 5V TTL signal to turn the beam on/off.

The fan output is as follows:
Fan OFF - both red and black wires are held at 12VDC.
Fan ON - Red wire 12VDC, Black wire pulled to GND.
(also supports PWM output at various levels, black wire is used for PWM signal while red wire is held at 12VDC.)

I had wrongly assumed the black wire would be held at GND while the 12VDC wire would be used to control the fan. So I assumed I had a GND reference available, so I built this level shifting circuit (which, of course, doesn't work due to black wire being pulled to 12VDC when off). Its purpose was to simply ground the TTL+ pin to the TTL- pin when 12VDC was present on the input, effectively inputting a logic 0 to the laser controller, or allow TTL+ pin to float high when 0VDC was present from the fan controller, inputting a logic 1 to the laser.  I realize this inverts the fan output (fan off = laser on) but that's not a problem.  And it did work when testing with a 12VDC power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fme6k0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, since the outputs of the fan controller both go to 12VDC when the fan is off, this doesn't work.  How can this circuit be re-designed in the simplest way possible (hopefully without requiring outside power) to shift this strange 12VDC signal to 0/5VDC TTL signal, or effectively short/open the connection between TTL+ and TTL- pins?  I guess a relay would work for simple ON/OFF controls, but that would preclude using PWM to control the laser...

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Spitballing, all you need to do is connect the fan black wire to the NPN base resistor, and use a common ground for the emitter. It will be inverted from the fan logic, but that's it.

Comment: That base resistor is way too high though. 12v - 0.7v ) / 100 ohms = .11 A or 110 mA. You risk burning out the transistor. A 1k or 470 ohm resistor is more appropriate.

Comment: I'll answer this tomorrow if no one else has. Don't have access to the schematic tool right now.

Comment: What was the purpose of the cooling fan? Why don't you need one anymore?

Comment: The fan in a 3D printer cools the newly extruded filament so that it solidifies quickly before it deforms under gravity. The OP is unlikely to try to use the machine as a 3D printer and a laser cutter at the same time.

Comment: sorry @Passerby I forgot to set the values for the resistors. They were supposed to be 1k.  Fixed now.  Also Q1 was supposed to be a 2N2222A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with a very simple circuit, which avoided the need to run extra ground or +5/12V lines.  I used a simple optocoupler and resistor.

Again this is an inverted control: when the fan is ON, the laser will be OFF.  Anything less than 100% output on the fan will result in the laser pulsing at the fan PWM frequency.

I have a Monoprice Maker Select 3D printer which uses RepRap compatible g-code.  To turn the laser ON, issue M106 S0, and to turn the laser OFF, issue M106 S255 gcode commands.

I am using the [J Tech Photonics Inkscape plugin](https://jtechphotonics.com/?page_id=1980) to generate laser g-code, and it doesn't support this type of inverted output. So it's necessary to do a search/replace in the gcode file to swap the M106 S255 and M106 S0 commands.

YMMV - hopefully helpful to someone!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxOni4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just solder two wires straight to the **Gate** and **Source** pins of the fan MOSFET on RAMPS board? So you will get 5V PWM signal straight from ATMega controller.

That is what I did - soldered two-wire JST-connector to the pins to make it unplugable. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the black wire gets pulled to 12VDC and the red wire sticks to 12VDC the entire time, you can just use a inverter to drive the whole thing - an inverting buffer like something in the 74xx series parts could work fine as a level translator.

Comment: I wanted to avoid needing to run extra 5V/GND wires to the printhead.